# which data type to store a longitude and a latitude in a SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I created a table with fields `map_latitude` and `map_longitude` in Sqlite Data Base with data type REAL.

But when I retrieved data from the database in Toast Message I see it with only zero decimal point.

for example:

```
15.31894  
store as 15.0
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use **Data-Type** [**`REAL`**](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

> The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating
>   point number.

Safe Approach is -> Using **`TEXT`**

Comment: i changed the data type to text and it works good now but i want to know why Real data type doesn't work with me ??

Comment: @MokhtarGhaleb Good question . Using TEXT is safe approach . http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/tip-when-real-not-real

Comment: yes i used text as you told me before thank you for your support